# How to fix "'TypeError: datetime.time' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, excel, python-datetime

I'm working on extracting data time and calculating there results but 00:00:00 values display in a different manner. Why is that ? and how can i fix it?"

I have already tried to read it as a string get a sublist of char and converted to a integer."

```
Ts = datetime.timedelta(hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0)
for i in range(0,len(cell_sl)):
    for item in cell_sl:
        trans = item[i]
        Ts = Ts + datetime.timedelta(
                hours=int(str(trans[:2])),
                minutes=int(str(trans[3:-3])),
                seconds=int(str(trans[6:]))
        )


print(Ts)
```

I expect the output to be for example 00:25:18, but I get 
`TypeError: 'datetime.time' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What is `cell_sl` ?

Comment: @beer44 it's a list containing strings i need to parse in the excel sheet, index_sl = [0,2] and cell_sl = ["00:00:00", "00:22:16"] the problem reside in elem[0] of cell_sl because it is displayed "1899-12-30 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your `trans` or your `item` values are *datetime.time* object's - thats what the error tells you:

> TypeError: 'datetime.time' object is not subscriptable

You cannot slice/subscript them like f.e. strings:

> ```
> trans = item[i]        # <-- this is a "subscription"  ...  either item is a datetime 
> Ts = Ts + datetime.timedelta(hours= int(str(trans[:2])),  # or trans is one
>                                minutes= int(str(trans[3:-3])), 
>                                seconds= int(str(trans[6:])))
> ```

Use the *hour, minute, second* attributes provided by [datetime.time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) instead:

```
Ts = Ts + datetime.timedelta(hours = trans.time.hour, 
                             minutes = trans.time.minute, 
                             seconds = trans.time.second)
```

**If you are unsure which one is it, use `print(type(item))` to see what type it is.**

---

Full example with *one* datetime value:

```
import datetime

Ts = datetime.timedelta(hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0)

print(Ts)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
Ts += datetime.timedelta(hours=now.hour, minutes=now.minute, seconds=now.second)

print(Ts)
```

Output:

```
0:00:00
10:24:17
```

Comment: Thank you @Patrick Artner for the answer but i'am still having the same problem, i tried your solution and here what i have experienced :                                                Ts = datetime.timedelta(hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0)
for i in range(0,len(cell_sl)):
    for item in cell_sl:
        trans = item[i]
        Ts += datetime.timedelta(hours = trans.time.hour, minutes = trans.time.minutes, seconds = trans.time.seconds)     
print(Ts)   Error : trans = item[i]

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Thank you again @Patrick Artner your answer helped me to find a solution, i did make some changes on my code through your answer and it did work at the end.